# How can i connect a spotlight to main camera so when moving character the spotlight will move with it?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I dragged the spotlight to be under the main camera
And dragged the C# script to the spotlight.
But the spotlight is not where the camera is and not following the character moving.

This is the script I'm using and it's working it's toggling the spotlight on/off:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private Light myLight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {



        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
        }

    }
}
```

In this screenshot you can see the spotlight on the floor. How do i connect it to the character or main camera so it will move with the character ?

[image: Spotlight not in place]

Comment: Isn't there some code to show? That would make it easier to give hints, I guess.

Comment: @Dilettant the script ? I will add it to my question. The script i did so far just toggle off/on the spotlight and it's working.

Comment: You might want to add in your script a FixedUpdate where you make the Spotlight transform equals to the camera transform (with an eventual offset on the position, otherwise the light source would be the player's eyes).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Transform `localPosition` of spotlight to `0.0, 0.0, 0.0`